# Problema para alinhar horizontalmente layout responsivo usando Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Agora com o cabeçalho deu certo. Preciso criar uma segunda ROW (linha)
Ela sera 4|4|4 e deverá ter uma imagem, e as outras 2 partes de texto.
Porém tenho 2 dúvidas. A primeira é, não sei o que faço para que a imagem fique menor que o tamanho original (por exemplo: uma imagem 1920x1080 fique ocupando o espaço de 200x200px) e seja responsiva.

A outra dúvida é que o texto fique alinhado ao lado dela como no Cabeçalho o formulario de busca e o texto LOGOUT ficaram:
Segue o código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="barranav">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="http://placecage.com/50/50" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>
                <!--<a href="" class="navbar-brand">TEST</a> interesante -->
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="text-align:center;">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="color:aliceblue;">LOGOUT</div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="corpo">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="panda2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> TEXTO DIV 5 a 8</div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> TEXTO DIV 9 A 12 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para deixar suas imagens responsivas usando o padrão do bootstrap, você pode usar a classe "img-fluid" ficando assim:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

E para modificar o tamanho você pode forçar via css, assim:

```
img {width: 200px; height: 200px;}
```

Sobre o outro ponto, você precisa falar pra div que ela é um container, dessa forma:

```
<div class="corpo container">
```

Asssim, diferente da div de cima, essa será encaixotada, se quiser fluída também, basta adicionar o container-fluid, mas de qualquer forma, pra usar a estrutura do bootstrap, você precisa informar qual quer usar.

Maiores informações veja:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#responsive-images